# Hide empty group in Grouptree

Tags: crystal-reports, reportviewer

I've got a report that is grouped by a column and displays only rows that meet a condition. 
The final report is looking fine, except that groups that are not visible in the report still show up in the grouptree of the reportviewer.
How can I make Grouptree show only the groups that are visible in the report?

The report sections are set up like this:

- The GroupHeader is always supressed.
- The Details section is supressed for every row that does not meet the
  condition.
- The Footer is supressed when the details section is empty (There's a
  counter that is increased for every shown row).

Answer (score 0):

You can add Running total field into report. Let it be just count and increase for each visible row of your group (evaluate it on condition used for row showing). Set for group section supressing with conditional formula `{#YourCountField}=0`

Comment: Already did that. The groups are already invisible in the report, but still show up in the reportviewer.